# Merged Layers turned into square shape cause by single layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, borders

What I did is merged the 30 layers of the map (Isabela Map Province - Philippines) and below is what happened.

How do i remove the inside map of the border?

I'm new to QGIS and I'm using QGIS 2.4 Chugiak.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing PolyGeo, I'm not good at english.

Comment: Are these maps available online?

Comment: Yes, they can be downloaded free at bswm.gov.ph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Vector->GeoprocessingTools->Dissolve and dissolve by an attribute (Dissolve Field) to merge subdivided polygons.

Comment: I tried dissolving all fields(one by one) on my map, but this is the most ok output http://i.imgur.com/KL9CTa4.png?1 . And thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: It looks possibly like you have tiny sliver gaps between the tiles you used in the merger.  Zoom right in on one of the lines to confirm.  If this is the case, the error lies with your merger process and possibly that the tiles were not cut right in the first place (maybe due to some mismatched projection between the grid used and the data).  Your best bet is to get the original data that was used to create the tiles.

Comment: http://imgur.com/LdP8PD5 , Yes! There is a tiny gaps between the tiles I've used!, and In your suggestion, what will I do at the original data?

Comment: http://imgur.com/hkWZZNU , tried a single file that it isn't merged. Did them also to dissolve ALL fields, but this happened. http://imgur.com/hkWZZNU :/